# npm command line - how to enter new commands after start

Tags: angular, npm

I can start npm with "npm start" command successfully on Visual Studio command prompt. Command Prompt title becomes "Lite-Server". It watches the file changes without any issues. However, the command line doesn't let me to enter any new commands. For example I cannot type "npm stop" or even a single letter.

Maybe I should not use Visual Studio command prompt, but I think it should not matter. Any ideas?

CG

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code, the easiest way to achieve this is to open multiple terminals and navigate between them.

[Click this link for more information on the integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)